# Coloring JPanel elements that are inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am drawing a chess board in Swing. I created tiles (jpanel) and then tried to add components to board(another jpanel). Each time a tile is added, i tried to set a color, either Black or White. Board has GridLayout. Board does add 64 tiles to it, but only one of the tiles get a color, the rest gets a default color. I tried changing tiles(jpanel) to buttons(JButton) (to see if components are added to board or not) and the program did add 64 buttons to the Board. So I am guessing there is no problem in layout and adding components,but rather something to do with updating the color?

So how can I change the color of these smaller jpanels(tiles) when I add them to the bigger Jpanel(Board)?

Program is as follows(don't mind the coloring scheme, i don't actually want a chess board):

```
class Tile extends JPanel{

        private final int width = 50;
        private final int height = 50;
        Color tileColor; 
        int xPos, yPos;


        public Tile(int xPos, int yPos, Color tileColor){

            this.xPos = xPos;
            this.yPos = yPos;
            this.tileColor = tileColor;

        }
         public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
             super.paintComponent(g);
             g.setColor(tileColor);
             g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, getWidth(), getHeight());

         }

    }

    class Board extends JPanel{

        private final int width = 400;
        private final int height = 400;

        private int numTiles = 8;
        private final Color black = Color.BLACK;
        private final Color white = Color.WHITE;

        private final int hGap = 2;
        private final int vGap = 2;


        public Board(){

            setLayout(new GridLayout(numTiles, numTiles,hGap, vGap));
            setBackground(Color.CYAN);

            Color tileColor;
            int yPos = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < numTiles; i++){

                int xPos = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < numTiles; j++){
                    if(j % 2 == 0 )
                        tileColor = black;
                    else
                        tileColor = white;


                    add(new Tile(xPos, yPos, tileColor));
                    xPos += 50;
                }
                yPos += 50;
            }
        }



        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(width,height);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

You're filling the color alright, but at xPos and yPos **relative to this JPanel**, meaning the color is way away from the JPanel's actual displayed region.

Solutions:

- Change xPos and yPos to 0 and 0
- Or better just call `setBackground(...)` in the constructor.